# Solving shuffle the array problem on leetcode in Rust

Tags: rust

```
fn shuffle(nums: Vec<i32>, n: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut res: Vec<i32>;
    let mut i = 0;

    while i < n {
        res.push(nums[i]);
        res.push(nums[n + i]);
        i += 1;
    }

    res
}
```

When I try to index the `nums` array to get a value at `[i]`, I get this error:

```
the type [i32] cannot be indexed by i32
the trait SliceIndex<[i32]> is not implemented for i32
required because of the requirements on the impl of Index<i32> for Vec<i32>
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only index `Vec` using `usize`s, so you have to cast your `i32`s to `usize`s in order to index into `nums`:

```rust
fn shuffle(nums: Vec<i32>, n: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut res = Vec::new();
    let mut i = 0;

    while i < n {
        res.push(nums[i as usize]);
        res.push(nums[(n + i) as usize]);
        i += 1;
    }

    res
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e772fdfcd2bcbab67b8dae13259d74ed)

Comment: but, why did u intialize the result this way ''let mut res = Vec::new();"?

Comment: @ahmdtalat95 in Rust all values must be initialized before they can be used, it's a compiler error otherwise. Also, if my answer helped you please accept it by clicking the gray checkmark under the answer score, thanks!